# iOS Phonegap multi-line text select bug?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, cordova

I am creating a Phonegap app that requires the user to select text inside a `p` element, and then "copy" the text which modifies it to me needs.

There is a problem, however, with selecting text inside the `p` tag. The text is retrieved from my server where it is outputted like so:

```
<p style="white-space:pre-wrap">Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue. Donec congue lacinia dui, a porttitor lectus condimentum laoreet. Nunc eu ullamcorper orci. Quisque eget odio ac lectus 


vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque faucibus vestibulum. Nulla at nulla justo, eget luctus tortor. Nulla facilisi. 

Duis aliquet egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor, lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
</p>
```

This will alow the text to retain the line breaks without me using `<br/>` tags, which do not currently work within my Javascript.

Anyways, when you try to select text in this element, the entire `p` element is selected instead. Here's the transition of what happens when you select a word, then move the bounds to select more text:

[image]

**NOTE:** The text is different in the first sequence because I took the screenshot with different text, but the effect is still the same.

I can't provide a jsFiddle for this as it seems to be only replicated in Phonegap, but I've uploaded my source to test: http://cl.ly/2w0O1d3l3h17

There is no JS in the project, but the HTML and CSS look like this:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="text">Adobe Acrobat Test Page
        Acrobat Reader is properly installed.
        Click here to go back to information about using PDF.

        Guidance for Using PDF Documents

            California Home

            Search

            My CA

        This Site

        Guidance for Using PDF Documents

        Patient Advocate Home
        About the Office

        Some documents on this Web site are available in Adobe Acrobat Portable
        Document Format (PDF). These documents are identified by the
        symbol.
        q What is PDF?

        About the Patient
        Advocate

        q

        Download Adobe Acrobat Reader

        q

        Viewing Requirements

        A Message from the
        Patient Advocate

        q

        How to Use a PDF Document

        q

        Electronic Fill-in-the-Blank PDF Forms

            q

            Accessibility Tools for Visually Impaired Users

        State of California HMO
        Report Card
        Tips on Exercising Your
        HMO Rights
        HMO Terms Explained
        Mobile Information
        Center
        Schedule a Meeting or
        Speaking Engagement

        What is PDF?
        PDF is a portable document format developed by Adobe Systems. PDF
        documents are widely used on the Internet, including the this web server, for
        several reasons:
        q A PDF has the same appearance, colors, fonts, graphics and layout as
        the printed document.
        PDF files can be viewed in the browser, or saved for off-line use or
        printed.

        q

        The Acrobat Reader software is freely available for most operating
        systems.

        q

        Events and Event
        Calendar

        q

        While the Reader software can't edit (change) a PDF document, it can
        copy text from the document and perform word or text-string searches
        of the document.

        Photo Gallery

        Return to Top

        http://www.opa.ca.gov/support/pdf/ (1 of 3) [12/26/2001 6:11:06 AM]

        Guidance for Using PDF Documents

        Viewing Requirements
        To view PDF documents you need to use a PDF file viewer such as Acrobat
            Reader or Acrobat Exchange from Adobe Systems Incorporated.
            You may download and install Acrobat Reader free of charge.
            Please upgrade your browser and PDF viewer to the latest version to
        avoid any problems.
        Contact Us
        Customer Service
        Survey
        Help with PDF
        Conditions of Use
        Privacy Policy

        To check if you have Adobe Acrobat Reader installed, click here. If you are
        prompted to download hit cancel, this means that you do not have it installed.
        Click here to download Acrobat Reader now.
        If you experience any problems with PDF documents, upgrading your
        browser and/or PDF viewer to the latest version usually solves the problem.
        If after upgrading your software you are still unable to view PDF documents
        click here to view Adobe's help section. You may also send E-mail to the
        webmaster for further assistance regarding PDF or technical issues
        concerning this Web site.
        Return to Top
        How to Use a PDF Document
        q Download Adobe Acrobat Reader
        q
        q
        q
        q

        Install Acrobat Reader on your computer.
        Start your web browser and locate a PDF document on the Web.
        Click on the hypertext link for the PDF file.
        If you want to save the file for future reference, follow your browser's
        instructions for saving files from the Internet (often this requires
        pressing the shift key while clicking once on the filename).
        Return to Top

        Electronic Fill-In-The-Blank PDF Forms
        NOTE: Use of PDF fill-in-the-blank forms does NOT include online
        submittal.
        Some PDF forms are available in a fill-in-the-blank format. Users now have
        the option—on certain OPA forms—to complete the PDF forms
        electronically, instead of manually writing or typing the information on a hard
        copy version.
        The form can be completed in several easy steps.
        q The user opens the PDF form in Acrobat Reader—in the browser or as
        a standalone product. The user can also save the PDF form to their
        computer system and open the form in Acrobat Reader at a later time.
        q Once the form is open, the user clicks on the desired field and a
        http://www.opa.ca.gov/support/pdf/ (2 of 3) [12/26/2001 6:11:06 AM]

        Guidance for Using PDF Documents

        q

        q

        blinking cursor appears.
        After the information has been entered in the field, the user can tab to
        the next field.
        After all the fields have been completed, the user can print out the
        page.
        NOTE: If the cursor is blinking in a field, the information in that field
        will not be printed. Hit "Return" or "Enter" and the information will be
        captured for all fields.

        Users with Acrobat Reader only, the entered data cannot be saved for later
        use.
        For those who have the entire Acrobat suite—Acrobat, formerly called
        Acrobat Exchange—the data can either be saved separately or as a part of the
        form. If you save the data-only, it will take up less disk space and can be
        imported back into the same form at any time, provided the form has not
        changed. For more information on exporting and importing form data, check
        your manual.
        Return to Top
        Accessibility Tools for Visually Impaired Users
        Access.adobe.com provides a set of free tools that allow visually disabled
        users to read documents in Adobe PDF format. These tools convert PDF
        documents into either HTML or ASCII text, which can then be read by many
        screen-reading programs.

        © 2000 State of California. Gray Davis, Governor. Conditions of Use Privacy Policy

        http://www.opa.ca.gov/support/pdf/ (3 of 3) [12/26/2001 6:11:06 AM]

        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.text{
    white-space:pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    height:300px;
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

---

One potential solution that I've found is to use `contenteditable="true"` on the `p` element, but this has some downfalls:

1. I can't allow for more tags to be created within the element
2. I can't have the keyboard showing

---

Another solution I've found is to remove the `pre` formatting. This, however, removes the line breaks, which I would ideally like to keep.

Comment: If you were to continue selecting downwards to the 'Guidance for using PDF...' line, does the select box start to play fair again?

Do you have the same problem if you encapsulate each paragraph with `<p>` tags?

Comment: I have not tested each paragraph with `p` tags. As for continuing to select downwards, it will select the entire `p` element. You can, however, move the bottom of the entire selection up, and it will begin to select letters like it should. Try out the example code I posted to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this is to put the entire contents in a `p` tag, or anything, then separate each paragraph that would normally be separated by a `<br />` with a faux-line break that looks something like this:

```
<a class="space"></a>
```

It can be any normally inline element, which we will then give the following CSS to:

```
.space{
    display:inline-block;
    height:15px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is that iOS'es native selection engine selects either separate words or the whole elements. And because you have a single `<p>` element holding the whole text the native selection engine select the whole `<p>` element when you try to select more than one line. What you should do is to "hint" the selection engine that you want to be able to select multiple lines. You can achieve that by placing each line of text into a separate [block level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements), for example `<div>`.

Here is an example script that parses text inside the `<p class="text">` element and puts each line of text into a separate `<div>` element preserving new lines, empty lines and spaces in the beginning of each line by using [non-breaking-space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) character entity.

```
var textElm = document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0],
    text = textElm.textContent,
    html = "";

html = text.replace(/([\t ]*)(.*)\n/g, function(match, spaces, text) {
    if (spaces === "" && text === "") spaces = " "; // Make sure empty lines are rendered by adding single &nbsp; to <div>
    return "<div>" + Array(spaces.length + 1).join("&nbsp;") + text + "</div>"
});

textElm.innerHTML = html;
```

[image]

Then you can also remove `white-space:pre-wrap;` from the CSS as it is no longer needed.

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work, and I can't. A main problem is that in order for this to work, `.text` can only be a certain number of characters...

Comment: Also, this method doesn't allow you to select text specifically across multiple `div`'s.

Comment: Yes, this is the limitation of iOS native selection engine. You can't select half of the text that starts in one element like `<p>` or `<div>` and half of the text that ends in the other element.

Comment: I didn't understood why you can't get it to work. The script above doesn't assume anything regarding the length of text inside `.text` element.

Comment: If the length of text exceeds a certain amount of characters, textContent fails. Try it wi more text. Furthermore, if you need to select parts of a word in one div and parts in another div, it will select the entire block element, instead of selecting until it reaches the carrot

Comment: I went to http://www.lipsum.com/ and generated a list with 5000 rows. Used them as the text and everything worked.

Comment: Regarding the partial selection, again, this is limitation of iOS native selection engine. You can't select text starting in the middle of one element and ending in the middle of another element. If you try to do so the engine will select whole elements.

Comment: There's no way to get around the last point? And I'm getting this error when running the code: http://i.imgur.com/K0reJgZ.png

Comment: I think not. Regarding the error: it seems that the `textElm` is undefined when you run this code. You should run this script after the DOM have been loaded. Place the script at the end of your `<body>` element or inside its "load" event handler: `<body onload="parseText();">`

Comment: Okay. Now even if I can get the code to work, it really doesn't answer the question that I originally posted.