# Inline line breaks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

*This is a lot to read, but if you read it all, it should make sense.*

I am working on an app that requires users to highlight text on iOS. The text is separated into paragraphs, with line breaks and paragraph breaks, and I decided I would simply use `<br />` tags for the line breaks, and start a new `p` element for each paragraph. The problem with Mobile Safari is that you can't individually select letters when the element you are selecting from is **not** inline. Instead, trying to highlight text would highlight the entire chunk of the paragraph, as it was displayed block..

To combat this, I decided I would replace all new-line characters (`\n`) with an inline element like so:

```
.space{
    height:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

So the HTML would look like:

```
Line one
<span class="space"></span>
Line two
```

And would output as:

> Line One
>
> Line Two

I thought, "Good job, you figured it out!"

---

Skip to today, where I found out that this is not the behavior I want. Since the text that the user is highlighting comes from a PDF file which is processed into plain text, there would be occurrences like this:

```
Hello there, this is a paragraph and\n 
it is continuing onto the next line and this line will continue and be wrapped by the set width of the parent
```

Which I would process as

```
Hello there, this is a paragraph and
<span class="space"></span> 
it is continuing onto the next line and this line will continue and be wrapped by the set width of the parent
```

Which would output as

> Hello there, this is a paragraph and
>
> it is continuing onto the next line and this line will continue and be wrapped by the set width of the parent

That's obviously not good! Now there's a whole new "paragraph-break" where there should be a "line-break". So, I figured I would make two different inline "break" classes, one for a single space, and one for a double space.

The double space element would act as the one above is, while the single space element would simply move the content onto the next line. So, this brings me to my actual question:

### How can I move text onto the next line using an inline-positioned element?

**Also, I cannot wrap the text in another element, such as `span`, so I can only use CSS to make an inline line break element and paragraph element.**

---

There are a couple of things that I have tried to get this to work. Instead of setting the `width` of the single space element to `100%` like I do with the double space element, I could instead calculate the width of the container and the width that the text takes up, and subtract the two, getting the width of the remaining space. This would allow me to push the content to the new line.

You can test this method here: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/ksvkk/12/

Problem with this method is that while I could determine the width, I couldn't determine it for multi-line text nodes. Also, this isn't flexible if the container size changes.

**A possible** idea that I had but couldn't get to work was to have the single space element have a `100% width`, and have the text push it so that it would push the newline down to the next line. Like I said, I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Interesting question, don't have time to dive into this now but perhaps I'll have a chance tomorrow.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Awesome. I feel like all it will take is the correct combination of styles.

Comment: But what if you simply use `<pre>` tag for text? Or `white-space: pre;` for the `<div>` block? Like that: http://jsfiddle.net/ksvkk/13/. It obviously won't require from you to replace the new lines with extra elements and will keep your markup more clear.

Comment: Nope. Already tried that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488751/ios-phonegap-multi-line-text-select-bug

Comment: _The problem with Mobile Safari is that you can't individually select letters when the element you are selecting from is not inline._ That is not entirely true—you just have to zoom in (and then it will let you highlight individual letters). Also, you're trying to combat native behaviour of an OS; that's a Sisyphean task.

Comment: What if instead you use a `textarea` and style it to look normal text: http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/ex3wu/ I just checked this on my iphone, and I was easily able to select individual words/letters.

Comment: @jacob I set the current zoom level to 1 and disable zooming, because that is a terrible UX. And it's not an impossible task. A textarea works well with selecting text, but if `readonly`, you can't select text.

Comment: @Charlie, I could select text with `readonly`

Comment: @jacob In your example, the `readonly` tag is misspelled as `readyonly`.

Comment: @Charlie, ah, that would explain it ^^, So without `readonly`, is that a sufficient solution?

Comment: @jacob Not really, as using a textarea then brings up the keyboard, and allows user entry. That's no good from a UX standpoint either. You could disable editing probably with JS, but that still doesn't solve the problem of the keyboard.

Comment: Terribly tedious, but might work: encase each word in a span tag, float them left, and terminate a line with an empty span set to clear both?

Comment: Not feasible in my scenario. When users highlight text in my app, it wraps the highlighted area in a span tag, and I would then have to rewrite the highlight function to exclude those span tags encompassing each word. ralph.m's second solution seems to be working, however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to offer a solution for an inline break: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/oliyz

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

    [data]:after {
    content: attr(data);
    white-space: pre;
    height: 0;
    }

    .doublespace{
    height:0;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>

    <p>Hello there, this is a paragraph and <b data='&#xa;'></b> it is continuing onto the next line and this line will continue and be wrapped by the set width of the parent</p>

    <p>Hello there, this is a paragraph and
    <span class="doublespace"></span> 
    it is continuing onto the next line and this line will continue and be wrapped by the set width of the parent</p>

</body>
</html>
```

In this example, only text is selected, rather than the whole block. I haven't tested in on an iPhone, but offering it just in case, as it's an interesting question.

Comment: I'm going to test this further, but so far it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

For the places where you don't want the appearance of a paragraph break, instead of this:

```
.doublespace{
    height:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

can't you just do this? (i.e. switch `inline-block` to `block`):

```
.singlespace {
    height: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Full example: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/koxlw

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

    .singlespace{
    height:0;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    }

    .doublespace{
    height:0;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>

    <p>Hello there, this is a paragraph and
    <span class="singlespace"></span> 
    it is continuing onto the next line and this line will continue and be wrapped by the set width of the parent</p>

    <p>Hello there, this is a paragraph and
    <span class="doublespace"></span> 
    it is continuing onto the next line and this line will continue and be wrapped by the set width of the parent</p>

</body>
</html>
```

=====================

(As noted in the comments, though, it's not hard to select a single character on the iPhone. Holding your finger on the text brings up a magnifying glass that makes for fine-grained selection of text. Unless I'm misunderstanding the issue here.)

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the issue: _The problem with Mobile Safari is that you can't individually select letters when the element you are selecting from is not inline. Instead, trying to highlight text would highlight the entire chunk of the paragraph […]_. When you hold your finger on a block element, you don't get the magnifying glass—it just automatically selects the whole "block" (which is insanely frustrating).

Comment: Hm, that's certainly not my experience. If I press on a word in a paragraph, the magnifying glass pops up and selects the word I pressed on, and I can expand or narrow that selection. Sorry if I am still misunderstanding. Anyhow, any comments on the code above?

Comment: @ralph.m Jacob is correct. If I used your method, I might as well use a `<br />` element to send text to the next line. In your example, if you attempt to select a word in the first paragraph, you may do so up until you reach the block element. Then, iOS selects the entire block element, meaning you can't continue to select individual letters in the following paragraph. Here's how your example works when a.) attempting to select text above the `.singlespace` element: http://i.imgur.com/41EflxR.png and b.) selecting text around the `.doublespace` element http://i.imgur.com/zz5OO15.png

Comment: OK, I thought you said the <br> element didn't work, but that another element between did. O well.